# Simple Way of Display the Result in the Same Page where Query was Made - Spring App

Tags: java, spring, jsp

I am new user of spring and java technology. I am trying to make a simple search application which take the query in search box and display the result in another pages. The  page that receive the search query is input.jsp -

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>    
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Input Form</title>
</head>
<body>
  <form:form action="output.html" commandName="query"  >
   <table align="center" >
        <tr>
            <td>Enter query :</td>
            <td><form:input path="query"/></td>
        </tr>       
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td><input type="submit" value="Search" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
  </form:form>


</body>
</html>
```

The page that display the result is output.jsp -

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>    

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Oputput Form</title>
</head>
<body>
   <table align="center" >
        <tr>
            <td>Result:</td>            
            <td><c:out value="${query.result}" /></td>
        </tr>      
  </table>

</body>
</html>
```

And the controller 'BaseController.java" is -

```
    @Controller
    public class BaseController {

        private SearchManager srchMgr = new SearchManager();
        private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(BaseController.class);

        @RequestMapping(value = "/input.html", method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public void getIp(Model model) {
            model.addAttribute(new Query());
        }
        @RequestMapping(value = "/output.html", method = RequestMethod.POST)
            public void showOutput(@ModelAttribute Query query, Model model){

                model.addAttribute("query", query);
    }
}
```

Now I am trying to display all of the things in output.jsp in input.jsp (the search result). In order to do this what changes should I made? I have tried with placing all the code from output.jsp to input.jsp and have changed @RequestMapping too. But it did not worked.Thanks in Advance

Comment: in `POST` method handler return to `input.jsp` instead of `output.jsp`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's pretty simple. All you need to do is to return the same page while returning the result.
Now there should be a question in your mind that when the first time you are visiting(before searching anything) what will be displayed in that page! Just use a null check parameter to see wheather the result is null(at the first time visit). If the result is null, then don't show anything.
That's all you need to do!